# How to fix Update Batch is Undefined Index?

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-3

I am trying to update multiple inputs, but every time I try to update, it says `undefined index: date_id`

Is there a way to fix this? I have already added `[]` or array symbols in my input tags but still the error keeps showing.

View:

```
<?php foreach($debtdate as $date): ?>

        <input type="hidden" name="date_id[]" value="<?php echo $date['date_id'] ?>" />

        <input type="number" name="amount[]"  />

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Controller:

```
    public function updateAmounts()
    {   


        $idlist = $this->input->post('date_id'); // <- This line is the error
        $marklist = $this->input->post('amount');

        $marks_data = array();

        foreach($idlist as $key => $id)
        {
            // we are filling an array with arrays here
            $marks_data[] = array('date_id' => $id, 'amount' => $marklist[$key]);
        }

        $this->debtor_model->updateAmounts($marks_data);    
      

        redirect('debts/view/'.$this->input->post('debtor_id'));

    }
```

Model:

```
    public function updateAmounts($marks_data){
    
        $this->db->update_batch('debt_date',$marks_data,'date_id'); 

    }
```

Comment: which is the line causing the error?

Comment: @Vickel - `$idlist = $this->input->post('date_id');` this line is the error please see updated question above. Thank you

Comment: How you called that update `updateAmounts` function ? Maybe you called it when display the view (GET request), so `$idlist = $this->input->post('date_id');` had no value